# Add css class to row in MVCContrib grid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, mvccontrib

I'm displaying a grid of data, and one of the attributes is an expiration date. If the expiration date is less than 60 days away, I'd like to highlight the row.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662543/how-to-style-rows-in-the-mvccontrib-grid-based-on-their-data), and used the answer there to use the `RowAttributes` function:

```
@Html.Grid(Model.PagedList).Columns(column =>{
    column.For(m => m.Name);
    column.For(m => m.ExpirationDate);        
}).Sort(Model.GridSortOptions)
.Attributes(@class => "grid")
.RowAttributes(m => new MvcContrib.Hash(@class =>
    (m.Item.ExpirationDate.Value.AddDays(-60) < DateTime.Now)) ? "warning" : "")
```

But I get a compilation error saying:

> **Cannot implicitly convert type 'MvcContrib.Hash' to 'bool'**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new[]
        {
            new MyViewModel { ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(70) },
            new MyViewModel { ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30) },
            new MyViewModel { ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90) },
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using MvcContrib.UI.Grid
@using MvcContrib
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>

@(Html
    .Grid(Model)
    .Columns(column => {
        column.For(m => m.ExpirationDate);
    })
    .Attributes(@class => "grid")
    .RowAttributes(m => new Hash(@class => (m.Item.ExpirationDate.Value.AddDays(-60) < DateTime.Now) ? "warning" : "" ))
)
```

You could also write an extension method for your model:

```
public static class RowAttributesExtensions
{
    public static Hash GetRowAttributes(this MyViewModel model)
    {
        return new Hash(@class => (model.ExpirationDate.Value.AddDays(-60) < DateTime.Now) ? "warning" : "");
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@(Html
    .Grid(Model)
    .Columns(column => {
        column.For(m => m.ExpirationDate);
    })
    .Attributes(@class => "grid")
    .RowAttributes(m => m.Item.GetRowAttributes())
)
```

which makes it more readable.